# Node using wrong UTC even if set TZ env

Tags: node.js, timezone

Why node is showing the wrong UTC?
It should show UTC -3 not UTC -2.

I'm in Brazil so my official UTC now is -3. If I try to do `new Date().toString()` on Chrome Console, its show UTC -3. When I run the same code on Node, its show UTC -2 even if I start the Node with TZ=America/Sao_Paulo doing `env TZ='America/Sao_Paulo' node`.

Where the UTC value came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was addressed in [IANA TZDB 2019b](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2019-July/000056.html).  Node missed the 2019b update, but [recently updated to the subsequent 2019c release](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/30356).  This is in Node.js LTS 12.13.1 [(see release notes)](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V12.md#2019-11-19-version-12131-erbium-lts-targos), and also in the current 13.2.0 [(see release notes)](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V13.md#2019-11-21-version-1320-current-mylesborins).

Update your Node.js version to resolve the issue.

Aside: The terminology in your question is slightly incorrect.  [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is the reference (`+00:00`).  When you refer to UTC-3 or UTC-2, those are referred to as *offsets*.  More specifically, "time zone offsets" or "UTC offsets" or "offsets from UTC".